# C# - How can i get header row from datatable and arrange it vertically down a column?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, datatable

How can i turn this datagridview from datatable
[image]

into this
[image]

Here is my code now. Any suggestion, comments, or sample code are highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            excelReader.Close();

            if (result != null)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = result.Tables[0];
                List<string> headers = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    headers.Add(col.ColumnName);
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
```

Comment: DataTable dt = DataSet1.Tables[0];

            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                cmbAllHeader.Items.Add(col.ColumnName);
            }

            cmbAllHeader.Text = "Select Column";

// foreach loop concept is good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();  
dataGridView1.DataSource = columnNames;
```

Or

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: I think it returns the length of the column. But it did change to vertically down a column. Can i know. Is this what they call LINQ?

Comment: Yes, this is LINQ . will return ColumnName and if you  bind with Grid, will be shown vertically as needed.

Comment: the columnNames did store the row values in array. But when i set it to dataGridView1.DataSource it shows the property of the array. Not the values in it. Can i know how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the Header to be visible like this:

**DataGridView.ColumnHeaderVisible = true;**

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = GridDataSource.Tables[0];
            
foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
   cmbSelectSearchBy.Items.Add(col.ColumnName);
}
cmbSelectSearchBy.Text = "Select Column";
```